# How do we formally distinguish between zero probability events that may and may not actually occur?

Tags: probability

Consider a random variable $X$ with pdf 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
3/2 &\text{ if } x\in[0,1/3]\cup[2/3,1] \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here, $P(X=1/6)=P(X=1/2)=0$, but $1/6$ and $1/2$ are somehow different, because the event $X=1/6$ *can actually happen*, but $X=1/2$ can't. How do you differentiate between values like $1/2$ that can't happen, and $1/6$ that can, and what do I need to know about a random variable in order to know whether a value is zero probability of one type or the other?

Comment: If only the pdf or cdf are given, it is impossible to differentiate between your two cases. You'd have to look at the function X itself to tell. From my experience, not much attention is paid to this in probability or statistics, but who knows something has been found.

Comment: The following links might provide some insight: [wiki:Null Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set), [wiki:Almost Everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).  Perhaps you could use the phrase "almost impossible" and "impossible" to describe the two outcomes.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446351/how-likely-unlikely-is-an-event-with-probability-1-0?rq=1) seems to go into some details related to your question and the answers there might be useful to you.

Comment: I think the way to tell them apart is with the PDF.  If $f(x) \gt 0$ then $X = x$ can actually happen, even though $P(X = x) = 0$.

Comment: Do you say $X=\frac{1}{2}$ cannot happen because its pdf has value 0 when $x=\frac{1}{2}$? Why does it follow that it can happen if the pdf has some non-zero value? If you look at the cdf it takes a constant value between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ rather than increasing. Does an increasing cdf mean a value can happen and a constant cdf mean it can't?

Comment: Why do you think that $X=1/6$ can happen and $X=1/2$ not?

Answer (score 0):

One way to differentiate these two cases would be to compute the probability of observing an outcome in some $\epsilon$ neighborhood around each point. For instance, with $\epsilon=\frac{1}{100}$, we see that the probability of observing an outcome between $\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{100}$ and $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{100}$ is $\frac{3}{100}$. Likewise, for the same $\epsilon$ neighborhood around $\frac{1}{2}$, the probability is zero. Thus, while the likelihood of observing an outcome of *exactly* $\frac{1}{6}$ is zero, you have a non-zero likelihood of observing an outcome in some small neighborhood around $\frac{1}{6}$, which is not the case with $\frac{1}{2}$ (provided you choose $\epsilon$ sufficiently small).